# dynamodb scan returning IEnumerable<T> object exception when iterating through IEnumerable

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I'm getting this exception when hitting the foreach in the following code:

```
`System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
Message=Specified cast is not valid.
Source=AWSSDK`

IEnumerable<FoodOutlet> foundOutletList = context.Scan<FoodOutlet>(
                    new ScanCondition("Postcode", ScanOperator.Equal, "3000")
);

List<FoodOutlet> foodOutletList = new List<FoodOutlet>();

foreach (FoodOutlet fo in foundOutletList)
{
    foodOutletList.Add(fo);
}
```

Comment: In which line are you getting the error?

Comment: within the line: foreach (FoodOutlet fo in foundOutletList)

Comment: Why are you assigning `foodOutletList` a new list after retrieving it from the `context`?

Comment: I had another issue, casting the list. Actually probably related! I think I figured what I did while converting to Entity Framework. I had latitude and longitude already in aws dynamodb for testing, and then I had them as floats in the object. This would make sense to be the casting. The error in Entity Framework clearly said they should be doubles. I'm rusty, and very early in a project and still exploring options. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written what "context" is. I believe that you are misusing the [Table Scan](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanMidLevelDotNet.html) operation
That is why the actual items aren't what you expect them to be.

If that is not the case - What is the dynamic type of the object foundOutletList? and if you can watch its members, what type are they?

Comment: `    AmazonDynamoDBConfig config = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig();
    config.ServiceURL = "http://dynamodb.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com";
    client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(config);
    context = new DynamoDBContext(client);`

Comment: ok, watch the sample in the Table Scan page I linked to. You need to first get a Table in order to scan on. You do not Scan the context.